# std::condition_variable::wait_until and wait for both not working with an expected waiting time

Tags: c++, multithreading

I consulted with the [wait_until example code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_until):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::condition_variable cv;
//std::mutex cv_m;
std::mutex cv_m[4];
//std::atomic<int> i{ 0 };

void OnRecive(int index/*char* data*/) {
    //ProcessData(data);
    std::thread(
        [index]() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m[index]);
            //auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            //if (std::cv_status::timeout == cv.wait_until(lk, now + 5000ms))
            if (std::cv_status::timeout == cv.wait_for(lk, (index+1)*1s))
            {
                cout << "time-out: file transfer failed.\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "no time-out: file transfer continuing.\n";
            }
        }
    ).detach();
}
void main() {
    thread th([]() {
        OnRecive(0);
        OnRecive(1);
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
        OnRecive(2);
        });
    //th.join();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
}
```

In this example, it's expected all 3 of OnRecive output `time-out`, since there is no cv.notify() to wake up them. But it's not working, sometimes (seems randomly), `no time-out` would be turned out.

I'm working on VS2019 + C++17 std.

[image]
[image]

I tried both wait_until and wait_for, all don't work.

I also tried to use one `mutex cv_m` and multiple `mutex cv_m[4]`, also don't work. Do you have a clue?

Edit:

I just tried the code with the [online compiler](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=887c7c40a7a1acb9) with GCC(C++23) for several times:

```
terminate called without an active exception
time-out: file transfer failed.
time-out: file transfer failed.
time-out: file transfer failed.
```

It works pretty well!

Comment: Could you clean up the commented/unrelated code?

Comment: You are not using the condition variable correctly. 1. Read up on spurious wakeups. 2. Do not use the same CV with different mutexes.  3. Last but not least, always join all threads, thank me later.

Comment: CV is used when you want to synchronize operations between two threads. You are using CV in one thread, what about other? What is CV in the thread waiting for?

Comment: @n.m., actually th.join(); is meaningless (yet I also tried it), because OnRecive just start 3 threads, no blocking.

Comment: @kiner_shah, just waiting for a time out.

Comment: No, *detaching* is meaningless (unless you are an expert and you know extremely well that you need detached threads for a specific reason, which you don't have). You also do neither join nor detach the (meaningless) thread you create in `main`.

Comment: @n.m., If I don't detach, how do I pass the code? What's the reason for using threading there?

Comment: "how do I pass the code?" I have no idea what you mean by that, but you don't detach by simply not calling `detach()`. Join all the threads *at the end of the program*, not immediately after creating the thread.

Answer (score 0):

1. `std::thread th` must be joined. otherwise `terminate` will be called.
2. One `condition_variable` with many `mutexes` is undefined behavior.
3. If you want to prevent spurious unblocking add `bool stop_waiting function` like this `cv.wait_for(lk, (index+1)*1s),[]{return false;})`.
4. `Detached threads` can run beyond your main so you will miss the results (for example if you run `OnRecive(100)`). So put `OnRecive()` in `thread` rather then `thread` in `OnRecive()` and then `join` `thread` when you see fit. `Detach` is not `flow control` but simply makes `thread` independent of the `object` that created it.
5. If the purpose of `std::thread th` to `join` previously `detached threads` it will not work and can be removed.